# Standalone GWT Design Viewer

Tags: gwt, gwt-designer, designview

I am using GWT in Eclipse, but I couldn't make use of GWT Designer. It keeps on giving me errors. With the same code, my friend is able to use GWT Designer in his Eclipse. And added to that, GWT Designer consumes a lot of memory.

So I just need to know if there are any GWT Stand alone Design apps, without Eclipse GWT Designer.
I don't need to use Eclipse for Design at all, since it already consumes more memory.
It would be better if there is any app to translate ui.xml files to design view at all.

Comment: could you paste the error your are getting?

Comment: !ENTRY org.eclipse.wb.core 4 4
!MESSAGE Designer [2.3.2.r35x201107161302]: Path must include project and resource name: /anothePro
!STACK 0
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Path must include project and resource name: /anothePro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GWT Designer is made as a Eclipse Plugin and there seems to be no Stand Alone GWT Designers as of now. Let's hope may be in future, someone pops it up.